# append exactly after some tag

Tags: jquery, html

**Html:**

```
<div class="form-group img-upload">
     <label class="control-label col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 btn green" style="text-align:center;">Add Image<span class="required" aria-required="true"></span>
     </label>
     <div class="col-md-7" id="prev_image"></div>
</div>
```

I want to append:

```
 <input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]" class="form-control hide img-btn" id="1">
```

exactly after 
`#img-upload>label>span`

My expected html after append:

```
<div class="form-group img-upload">
    <label class="control-label col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 btn green" style="text-align:center;">Add Image<span class="required" aria-required="true"></span>
        <input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]" class="form-control hide img-btn" id="1">                                
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-7" id="prev_image"></div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
var fileInput = '<input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]" class="form-control hide img-btn" id="'+ id +'">';
('.img-upload>label>span').append(fileInput);
```

but it does not work did not show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the
>   set of matched elements.

```
$('.img-upload>label>span').after(fileInput);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dftwo2kq/)

You can also use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$(fileInput).insertAfter('.img-upload>label>span');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jq1j30ot/)

> The `.after()` and `.insertAfter()` methods perform the same task. The
>   major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of
>   the content and target. With `.after()`, the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container after which the content is
>   inserted. With `.insertAfter()`, on the other hand, the content precedes
>   the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on
>   the fly, and it is inserted after the target container.

Answer (score 1):

Append means after the content if the mentioned element.

*ie* you need to use just `$('.img-upload>label').append(fileInput)` as selector. Which means the `fileInput` will be appended to the end of the label.

```js
var id = 1;
var fileInput = '<input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]" class="form-control hide img-btn" id="'+ id +'">';
$('.img-upload>label').append(fileInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group img-upload">
     <label class="control-label col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 btn green" style="text-align:center;">Add Image<span class="required" aria-required="true"></span>
     </label>
     <div class="col-md-7" id="prev_image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution won't work if `span` would not be last element of `label`. Like http://jsfiddle.net/pmruoej3/. Otherwise its ok.